# How to post JSON data from Arduino?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, http, json

I want to post data that I'm getting from the sensor every 5 seconds to my application in JSON format. Initially, I'm getting data as int and converting into String.

For example:

if data=15, it is converting into string.

```
String st=String(data);
```

Now I want to post `st` every 5 seconds.

```
    int S2 = http.sendRequest("PUT", "{\"itemId\":\"64006A962B71A1E7B3A0428637DA997C.327681\",\"item\":{\"Properties\":{\"AssetSensorDistance\":\"+st+\"}},\"operationType\":\"Update\",\"originalItem\":{\"Work_Order\":{\"ItemId\":\"64006A962B71A1E7B3A0428637DA997C.327681\"},\"Properties\":{\"AssetSensorDistance\":\"+st1+\"}}}");
    Serial.print("Sensor Status: ");
    Serial.println(S2);
```

st1 is the previous value, it is printing httpcode -2(invalid Syntax).

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I take it, at some other point in your program, you are telling it *where* to post the data to?

Comment: To My Application

Comment: please provide detailed information in your question about what you are observing. ... there appears to be a contradiction in your statements

Answer (score 2):

The string

```c++
"{\"AssetSensorDistance\":\"+st+\"}"
```

contains a literal "+st+". If you want to do string concatenation, you
should terminate the string with a double quote character, then add st,
then use another double quote to start the second part of the string:

```c++
"{\"AssetSensorDistance\":\""+st+"\"}"
```

Comment: it displaying as +st+ in my application instead of value

Comment: @AnneLingesh: That's what I wrote in my answer: you have **a literal “+st+”** in your string.

Comment: I didn't understand @Edgar Bonet 2

Comment: `it displaying as +st+ in my application instead of value` ... your post says that it does not work, that you are getting `invalid Syntax` ... which is it? you are either getting some data to your application, or you are not getting data to your application.  .... update your question with more information

Comment: Getting data but which I'm not expected, I want to display value in my application not st(text)

Comment: @AnneLingesh: Please, read my answer again **slowly**, paying attention to each word and punctuation. If there is still something you do not understand, tell us what **exactly** you do not understand.